# java - How do I display a character array in a JTextField

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, character, jtextfield

I'm trying to create a hangman game where dashes will display for the user and if they click on the correct button, a letter will replace the dashes. This worked when I was using the console to output all the data, but after I changed to GUI, it wouldn't work no matter what I tried. It seems that the JTextField won't accept a character array.

```
    private static JTextField txtDashes;
    static char [] dashes = {'-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'};

            txtDashes = new JTextField();
            txtDashes.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            txtDashes.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            txtDashes.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            txtDashes.setBounds(39, 207, 218, 46);
            gameScreen.add(txtDashes);
            txtDashes.setColumns(10);

            for (int i = 0; i < dashes.length; i++){
                   txtDashes.setText(dashes[i]); //Error occurs here
            } //End of for loop
```

I'm only experienced in about 5 months of java coding and can't seem to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it wouldn't work no matter what I tried"? Are you getting an error? The wrong output?

Comment: What kind of error your get?

Comment: Well, the answer is "covert it to a string first". Not a very useful question/title is it? Make the title *mean* something per the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass a `String` to `setText()` method 
dashes is a `char` array.you can't set a char to a textfield .you have to convert char to String first

use

```
txtDashes.setText(String.valueOf(dashes[i]));
```

or

```
txtDashes.setText(dashes[i] + "");
```

edit

---

`setText()` replace exiting text and set new text.if you want to show all array chars, first append it to a string throw a loop and from outside of loop `setText()`

like this

```
String s="";
for (int i = 0; i < dashes.length; i++){
    s+=dashes[i];
} 
txtDashes.setText(s);
```

note .string append inside a loop is not good you can use `StringBuilder` for that

Comment: An output was created using your method, but it only 1 dash was displayed instead of the 12 that I needed to be displayed.

Comment: @SamerAlabi how do you want to display them .as `------` or `- - - -` or ??

Comment: I want them to display as ------

Answer (score 0):

Your can use Fast Snail method or you can use String instead of char.

```
static String [] dashes = {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove for loop in your code. Instead use **Arrays.toString** to convert array to String:

```
txtDashes.setText(Arrays.toString(dashes));
```